# drupal 8: how to redirect route with route parameters?

Tags: drupal-8

I have created dynamic route in drupal8 with parameter. Now i need to redirect to this page based on user action. How can this be achieved?

Page sample router code as below example:

```
domain_site_settings.config_form:
  path: '/admin/config/domain/domain_site_settings/{domain_id}/edit'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\domain_site_settings\Form\DomainConfigSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Domain site settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'domain site settings'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 9):

Finally i found answer for this question.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$path = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('domain_site_settings.config_form',
    ['domain_id' => 'drupal_com'])->toString();
  $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
  $response->send();
```

Comment: I'll just mention that if this is in a route controller, Symfony expects the controller to return a Response object. Instead of calling $response->send(), just return the redirect response.

Answer (score 4):

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;  


$url = Url::fromRoute('YOUR CUSTOM ROUTE');
  $query = [
    'searchQuery' => [
      'searchType' => $searchType,
      'title'      => $title,
    ],
  ];
  $path = $url->setOption('query', $query);
  $path = $path->toString();

  $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
  $response->send();
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

...

$url = Url::fromRoute('example_route.subpath', [
  'param1' => 23,
  'param2' => 'xyz'
]);
return new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
```

Or if you have access to `FormStateInterface` object

```php
$form_state->setRedirect('example_route.subpath', [
  'param1' => 23,
  'param2' => 'xyz'
]);
```